# Inline functions in Linux device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a device driver. I have a questions to ask:

Will it be correct to have inline function declared in .c file?

I am speaking with respect to device driver meant for the linux kernel. I have a function, which is quite short in terms of function body and it is exported from one module to another. Do you think, I can declare it as an inline in the .c file or I need to move this function declaration along with the EXPORT_SYMBOL line to a .h file just because it is inlined? What is the standard Linux kernel practice?

```
For ex -> something like this?
inline void hello_world( )
{............
return;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(hello_world);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is more a matter of coding convention than everything else. Ask on http://kernelnewbies.org. And your code will export the *non-inlined* function.

Comment: In case of device driver programming, if you have a/many function/functions that would be called or used by multiple modules then what you can do is just create a ".c" file and export all the functions to the kernel using EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL. Then such exported functions are recognized as "kernel symbol". While utilizing or calling these exported function, you need not include any files nor their prototype are to be defined. Just export it and then you call it from any other module. But make sure about the "license" under which you are exporting.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't declare a function to be `static`, the non-inlined version will be included in the compiled code even if it is declared `inline`, precisely to enable code from other compilation units to call the function.
Obviously there will not be any optimisation across function calls when called from outside the compilation unit, unless whole-program optimisation/link-time optimisation is enabled.

Comment: A `static inline` function would also be included in the compiled code if it appears outside of an inlined call, e.g. as a function pointer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, what I was trying to say is that you actually have to work for it if you want to make the compiler omit inlined functions (or functions that are never called). But if the function is defined as `static`, you shouldn't be able to call it from outside the compilation unit even if it wasn't optimised away.